# Unable to execute Snowflake COPY Command through Java

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am unable to load data from a stage on SnowFlake using java.

I don't see any errors but data is not loaded from stage "mystage" to table "TESTTABLE "
Code:

```
Connection connection =  DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, _connectionProperties);
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.executeQuery("copy into TESTTABLE (id, name) from (select $1, $2 from @mystage/F.csv.gz t);");
```

If I run same command in SnowFlake console, data is getting loaded into table "TESTTABLE " properly.

Answer (score 1):

We do not know to which database/schema the default connection points to. I would try to use fully qualified table name:

```
statement.executeQuery("copy into <db_name>.<schema_name>.TESTTABLE (id, name) from (select $1, $2 from @mystage/F.csv.gz t);");
```

Comment: Yes, ideally we should provide db and schema name too.

Answer (score 0):

By mistake I had comment out `connection.commit();` that was the problem.